# Wrong keyboard layout in Remmina and Windows Server

Tags: keyboard, rdp, remmina, layout

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise server, with which I'm connecting with remmina to it.

When I press <kbd>/</kbd> in the num pad, it writes a `-` instead of `/`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 23):

I solved this issue enabling the following option at Remmina: Preferences / RDP / Use client keyboard mapping

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: ensure all servers and all admin workstations all have the same keyboard lay-out.

In the end you'll settle for "US, Alternative International" (Linux) and "US QWERTY - International" (Windows) when enough foreign countries come on-line...

**Note to the low quality reviewers:** That's it: 30 years of experience.  Nothing else works flawlessly...